Docker can't access network IP
I am running a flask app on a Docker container. App is running on all the addresses 0.0.0.0.
But I can only access the local host ip.

Application is accessible at 127.0.0.1:500 but not 172.18.0.2:5000. I am running docker on windows. I tried to ping the ip and the result is request time out. The docker file and docker-compose file content is as follows:-
docker-compose.yml:-
services:
 web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/app

dockerfile:-
FROM python:latest
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install flask
COPY . .
CMD ["flask","run","--host","0.0.0.0"]


What is the 172.18.0.2 address?  That looks like a Docker-internal IP address; that won't be usable anywhere other than a native-Linux system, and then calling from the same host, and it's usually unnecessary to look it up at all.

Yo! Docker containers run in their own isolated network by default (e.g., bridge network). The container's internal IP (172.18.0.2) is part of this network and is not directly accessible from your host machine. When you map ports in docker-compose.yml (e.g., 5000:5000), Docker binds the container's port 5000 to your host's loopback interface (127.0.0.1).
